# How to properly disable higlight on HTML element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an element with text in it and in between text there are `span` elements. When I highlight the parts of the text with the `span` elements in it, it shows those elements text.
I looked for a solution and found the following css values, these should disable highlight and by the look of it, it does, but in code the values are still there.

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
 -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
   -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
     -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                              supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
```

In code I am getting the highlighted text like this `window.getSelection().toString()`.

I cant find any other way to disable highlighting and dont understand why these css values dont work.
What am I doing wrong? What other ways are there to disable highlight?

Comment: You can try using canvas to render the text.

Comment: are you using this on many elements ??

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224433/how-can-i-disable-highlighting-in-html-or-js

Comment: @AdamAzad Could you write an answer?

Comment: @AlaaKaddour yes, that seems to answer for firefox. I need this on all browsers